# rails new_booking_path takes to POST instead of GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to link my search query page to a booking page. Search query page has a list of cab operators. When I try to add the following link, it takes me to a POST request for booking/new instead of GET request:

```
<%= button_to "Book", new_booking_path(fare: print_price(fare_airport(operator, cat, distance))) %>
```

Obviously this leads to routing error, as rails doesn't define a POST request for the new action. it does, however, take the fare parameter that i pass as a part of the request:

```
http://localhost:3000/bookings/new?fare=840.00
```

I tried to force this link to a GET request, as follows:

```
<%= button_to "Book", new_booking_path(fare: print_price(fare_airport(operator, cat, distance))), method: :get %>
```

This works, but it doesn't take up the fare (or any other) parameter that I pass as a part of the request, as following:

```
http://localhost:3000/bookings/new?
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: passing a parameter to the `new_booking_path` should not generate a POST request. can you print your routes table here ?

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :bookings

  resources :airport_fares

  resources :cabcategories

  resources :operators

  get 'search/result'

  get 'distance/edit' end

Comment: [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) generate form not link. Please read carefully documentation.

Comment: that should be the issue..try `link_to` instead

Comment: link_to works, thanks guys! but how do I add a button to this?

Comment: You can just style it to look like a button. do you use Bootstrap ? you can use `btn` class to make it look like a button and you can pass as option like this: `<%= link_to "Book", new_booking_path(fare: print_price(fare_airport(operator, cat, distance))), class: "btn" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button_to` not suppose to create any `get` request. Here is button to helper http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to . If you want `get` request then you have to use `link_to` and make design changes to make it look like button.

Here one helpful link for this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/